# Knowing how many images are applied to a reduction

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to know across any type of reduction in Google Earth Engine, how many observations or images are in the stack that is being reduced, on a per pixel basis?

Here is an example of a reduction, but this would be accessible for any type of reduction: percentile, mean, linear fit, max/min, etc.

```
//This function masks clouds and adds quality bands to Landsat 8 images.
var addQualityBand = function(image) {
  return maskClouds(image)
    //NDVI
    .addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']))
    //time in days
    //.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
};

var ALPS_collection_2010= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2010-1-1','2010-12-31')
  .map(addQualityBand);
// Create a greenest pixel composite.
var ALPS_greenestPixelComposite_2010 = ALPS_collection_2010.qualityMosaic('nd');
// Display the results.
var vizParams = {bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'], min: 0, max: 0.4};
var ALPS_2010_mask = ALPS_greenestPixelComposite_2010.clip(Alps);
Map.addLayer(ALPS_2010_mask, vizParams, 'Mask applied to 2010 composite');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imageCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.count())` will count the number of images unmasked at each pixel (per band) in the collection.

To visualize the number of images which are contributing to your quality mosaic:

```
Map.addLayer(
  ALPS_collection_2010.reduce(ee.Reducer.count()),
  {min: 0, max: 50, bands: ['nd_count']});
```

The `nd_count` band of the output is counting the number of images with `nd` bands unmasked at that pixel.